# Nginx keeps trying to serve a file?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

This is my nginx.conf

```
events {
}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        rewrite_log on;

        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
            return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        location /.health {
            return 200 'OK';
        }

        location /.status {
            stub_status;
            server_tokens on;
        }

        location ~ ^\/([^.][^\/]*)(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http://$1.$DISCOVER$2$is_args$args;
        }
    }
}
```

How can this config, which clearly returns a static response for `/.health` and has no other routes, possibly be having this error?  At no point was nginx directed to look for a file.

```
[error] 16#16: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/_health" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.1.21, server: localhost, request: "GET /_health HTTP/1.1", host: "10.0.0.241"
```

Comment: The request shows "/_health", not "/.health".

Comment: Ya copy/paste error when making this post.  I was originally using /.health and thought it might be doing weird things around assuming file extensions...

After struggling with this for several hours, I think I was just not putting the nginx.conf in the right place.  Deploying now...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had a regression around properly placing the nginx.conf file.  I was too focused on routing logic to notice, but the main evidence is that there was an nginx welcome page from the default nginx.conf.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).